# Access to the .co Zone File?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, whois

*Not sure if SuperUser is the right place to ask this, feel free to move accordingly.*

I've been looking for how/where to get access to the complete **.co zone file**, but so far I only found a couple of old forum postings where a few users try to sell some outdated and *reverse-engineered* (*What does that mean anyway... Did someone brute-force all the ≃ 37<sup>63</sup> possible combinations?*) zone file for a substantial amount of money ($1,000) with no access to updates whatsoever.

Where (if at all available) can I get access to this zone file? Googling revealed fruitless so far.

I also contacted go.co support a week or so ago asking this question but I'm still waiting for a reply...

Comment: Why do you think you deserve a copy?  Top level zones are secret to minimize spammers and other abuse.

Comment: @Zoredache: gTLD zones are not secret, I suppose there's some kind of similar access program for this ccTLD since it's considered like a gTLD. As for the justification, I can provide it to the registrar / TLD authority if needed - but, if it eases your concerns, my purposes are no where near from being nefarious in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this [knowledge base answer](http://support.go.co/customer/portal/articles/1325686-does-co-internet-provide-access-to-the-co-zone-file-?b_id=497):

> **Does .CO Internet provide access to the .CO Zone File?**
>
> Last Updated: Oct 07, 2013 03:30PM COT
>
> No.  Currently, access to the .CO Zone File is not available to the general public.  .CO Accredited
>   Registrars and Affiliate Partners may apply and be granted access to
>   the .CO Zone File based upon signing a Zone File Sharing Agreement and
>   paying a one-time fee.  Access is granted on a case-by-case basis. 
>   Interested parties should contact Partners@go.co for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The [registrar information](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/co.html) for the Colombia domain gives ".CO Internet S.A.S."
as the sponsoring organization with http://www.go.co/ as their website.

The best way to get their zone file is to contact this company and ask.
You will need of course to furnish a valid reason and might be charged (or not) for this service.

Another address might be the [DatCat collection : Passive DNS Zone Files](http://imdc.datcat.org/collection/1-06YH-G=Passive+DNS+Zone+Files),
a project run by the Indiana University. You will need to contact the project administrator, (if the project is still running), and of course give a valid reason.
Passive listening to DNS requests will only give you the domains that are actively in use.

Comment: I contacted go.co partner support already, still no word from them. +1 for the Passive DNS zone files, they might prove useful if everything else fails (and they don't mind sharing them with me).

Comment: The ccTLD (country code top level domain) for .co costs $27 at [ViewDNS.info](http://viewdns.info/data/).

Comment: The [go.co blog says that they had over 1.5M domains](http://www.go.co/blog/2013/09/26/co-to-launch-eight-european-languages-as-idn-in-october/) as of September 26, while the viewdns.info package only counts 1,090,681. It's not the only one: [`.pt` ccTLD has 584,757 registered domains](https://www.dns.pt/en/domain-register-evolution) but ViewDNS only counts 126,900. With such huge descrepancies, I don't find that data to be very reliable.

Comment: For .co this makes two thirds of the data. You could ask them the reason for the missing domains (maybe passive dns again?).

Comment: I could do that, but I doubt the missing domains don't have DNS servers configured - taking the `.pt` ccTLD as an example, they only have about half of the 237,355 active domains (excluding the ones registered via ENH). My guess is, they are just brute-forcing the WHOIS system with common words and that doesn't guarantee that they are always up-to-date (plus, they don't seem to release updates for their packages). Either way, 1/3 of missing domains is really a lot for my purposes. I'll keep an eye on it though, and see how their count evolves.

Comment: If go.co don't answer, the [registrar information](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/co.html) for the Colombia domain also gives emails for their contact persons. But [read this](http://www.iana.org/reports/2009/co-report-24nov2009.html) for perhaps the reason why you are having these difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know a place where you can get co. zone file. I once needed an ar. and used a database I bought from these guys https://alldomainsdb.com/. I think you can buy the whole database with all kinds of zone files or a specific one, you have to make a request. Price is high and you must first contact the guys, so it takes some time and money, but the list was big so I guess it's worth the try